# Merging of cell not working in Python PPTx

Tags: python, python-pptx

**My Code**:

```
path =r"Sample PPT.pptx"

prs = Presentation(path)
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Summary Table"
shapes = slide.shapes

""" Putting the table in placeholder"""

placeholder = slide.placeholders[13]
graphic_frame = placeholder.insert_table(rows=df.shape[0]+2, cols=df.shape[1])
table = graphic_frame.table

"""Merging cells and naming them """
start_cell = table.cell(0, 0)
end_cell = table.cell(1,1)
start_cell.merge(end_cell)
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: '_Cell' object has no attribute 'merge'

**Python - 3.5.x**

Any help on why this error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was added relatively recently (v0.6.14, 2018-09-24).

Check your `python-pptx` version, I expect you need a `pip install -U python-pptx` :)

Comment: @scany: Need your help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757127/fit-a-picture-in-ppt-placeholder